# get libelle from FK

Tags: php, laravel, model

I may have a newbie question. I need to access to the field "name" of a linked table.

I've got a customer table with a country_id linked to a country table (easy).

Into my customer model, I defined the following function

```
public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
}
```

So, into my CustomerController, I access to the country name with the following code.

```
echo ($customer->country_id != null ? $customer->country->name : '');
```

But, what I'd like to to, is to change the Customer controller like that :

```
echo $customer->country_name;
```

So, now, my stupid question is how to write my model to allow such a stupid feature ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My colleague answered to my question, I just forget to add parenthesis to my customer controller.

Controller :

```
echo $customer->paysname();
```

Model :

```
public function paysname() {
    return (is_null($this->pays_id) ? '' : $this->pays->name);
}
```